# Trying to remove '1/2, 3/4, 1/3' values in excel using pandas

Tags: excel, pandas

I have a practice column with these values in excel

```
   apple
0  1 1/2
1  2 1/4
2  3 3/4
```

Excel turns these values into Fractions, so the output is like this:

```
   app
0  1.50
1  2.25
2  3.75
```

All I am trying to do is a find/replace so the output turns into this

```
   app
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

I've tried all kinds of things, but cant get it to work. I know how to do the find/replace part, just not how to remove the decimals or better yet, the fractions.

This are two different versions of turning the fractions into string values

```
fraction_df=df.astype({'app':'string'})
df['app']=df['app'].astype('string')
```

and then I tried to run find/replace

```
df=df.replace(['1/2','3/4','1/3'], '', regex=True)
```

A simple problem, but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: What do you see in the formula bar when you select the file with `1 1/2` in it?

Comment: What is the output of `df.to_dict('list')`?

Answer (score 0):

To convert `1.5` to `1` do the following:

```
df['app'] = pd.to_numeric(df['app']).astype(int).astype(str)
```

To convert `1 1/2` to `1.5`:

```
df['app'] = (df['app']
 .str.extract('(?P<a>\d+)\s+(?P<b>\d+)/(?P<c>\d+)')
 .astype(int).eval('a+b/c')
)
```